# Remove / add CSS class on input focus / blur

Tags: jquery, css, html, focus, blur

I have a form with some input fields and a little `<div>` to the right of each input with a little description. What I want is to enable a CSS class for each input's own `<div>` with it's own description.

I have made a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/VL2FH/8/.
This uses the `<div>` :hover state on the input's focus state.

What I want to ask is: Is there some sort of a "shortcut" so I don't have to make:

```
$('#submit_name').bind('blur', function(){
   $('#submit_name-desc').removeClass('input-desc-hover').addClass('input-desc');
});
$('#submit_name').bind('focus', function(){
  $('#submit_name-desc').removeClass('input-desc').addClass('input-desc-hover');
});
​
```

For each input field in the form.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/VL2FH/11/

Comment: Exactly like this! This works absolutely perfect! Could you make an answer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can generalize the `focus and blur` callback like this

```
$('input').on('blur', function(){
   $(this).next('div').removeClass('input-desc-hover').addClass('input-desc');
}).on('focus', function(){
  $(this).next('div').removeClass('input-desc').addClass('input-desc-hover');
});
```

If your description `divs` are next to the input element, it will work fine.

And it's better to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) for event binding.
    ​

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/VL2FH/11/

Comment: +1 for a simple solution. I tend to over-complicate things :)

Comment: Thank you a 1000 for this :)

And this solution I can reuse on the site where I have different forms with different names / id's etc, without adjusting it!

Comment: @MortenHagh, You are most welcome, Sir. Glad to be able to help.

Comment: This helped me ;) I used with `.parent` instead `.next` and other tweaks. but was very helpful :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can also achieve the same effect in CSS only by using the adjacent sibling selector `+` so that any `.input-desc` directly following a focused input will have the different rules applied:

```
input:focus + .input-desc {
    cursor: default;
    width: 265px;     
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #aaaaaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #aaaaaa;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #aaaaaa; 
    animation:desc 0.3s;
    -moz-animation:desc 0.3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:desc 0.3s; /* Safari and Chrome */  
}
```

The adjacent sibling selector is support in modern browsers and Internet Explorer from version 8. ( http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector )

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VL2FH/14/

Answer (score 2):

Check this bellow example program

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function()
                {

                    $('#submit_name').bind('blur', function()
                    {
                        $('#submit_name-desc').removeClass('cls1').addClass('cls2');
                    });

                    $('#submit_name').bind('focus', function()
                    {
                        $('#submit_name-desc').removeClass('cls2').addClass('cls1');
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <style>
                .cls1
                {
                    background-color: #ccc;                
                }

                .cls2
                {
                    background-color: #fff;
                }
                .submit_name-desc
                {
                    height: 30px;
                    border: 1px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="text" id="submit_name" />
            <div id="submit_name-desc">
                Name Description
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead of ids for selecting elements. If your input elements have `submit-name` class and your descriptions `desc` class, you could do it like this:

```
$('.submit-name').bind('blur', function(){
    $("~ .desc", this).first().removeClass('input-desc-hover').addClass('input-desc');
}).bind('focus', function(){
    $("~ .desc", this).first().removeClass('input-desc').addClass('input-desc-hover');
});
```

`$("~ .desc", this).first()` will select the first sibling of input element (`this`) with a class `desc`.

Here's an updated jsFiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/miroslav/VL2FH/13/

**Edit**

[Joy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169903/119230) with `$(this).next()` is much better though.